# Eclipseがsvnリンクが表示されなくなりました

Tags: eclipse

Eclipseで以下の画面の状態になってしまい、ファイルが表示されなくなってしまいました。
こちらどうしたら対処できるのか教えていただけないでしょうか？

[image: e]

Comment: エラーメッセージは極力 **文字のまま** 質問文に貼り付けてください。やむなく画像で貼る場合も画面キャプチャを使用した方がよいでしょう。 / 貼られた画像ではモアレが発生してしまっており非常に見づらいです。

Comment: ワークスペースがおかしくなっている気がします。[Eclipse が正常に起動できなくなったら試すこと](https://neos21.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/03/01/080152)の手順にしたがって回復できるかお試しください。[SO本家の類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15130339/8248751)

Comment: 申し訳ありません。インターネット接続ができないPCで写真をケータイからとなりました。